# For what purpose i can use Buildview and finishView of symfony forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I tried hard but still could not get , for what purpsoe , i can use buildview and finish view in symfony2.

can someone please give me some simple example how can use it.

I am trying to learn symfony by using all its functions

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use buildView and finishView methods in your type to pass new view vars to the form template. You can pass stuff from form options or form data class for example.

Method buildView is run before children views are built so you cannot access child views there (then you should use finishView which are run after children views are built).

[bulidView example](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/FormType.php#L40)

[finishView example](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/FormType.php#L108)

[second buildView example](https://github.com/ollietb/OhGoogleMapFormTypeBundle/blob/master/Form/Type/GoogleMapType.php#L52)

Comment: you should link to those specific versions of the file where the line numbers are correct.